# Finding x values for peaks in graph

Tags: pattern-matching, neural-network

I am trying to find the hours where my server load goes high (peak hours). As per what I know and have read, I can employ shape matching to find a peak, and for that I can use neural networks, etc.

But this will only tell me that the input is a peak or not. I wont be able to pass in a graph of my daily server usage and have it tell me the peak hours.

Pardon me, if the question is too idiotic, but trust me I have no leads on how this might be done. All my research is pointing to ways to find a peak, whereas I need to find where the peak exists in a data set, and there might be more than one such peaks too.

Answer (score 0):

So, you have an algorithm to detect peaks but you don't know how to find peak hours. The obvious idea is to collect peak rate per hour and build a histogram. Then find peaks in that histogram.

Or am I missing something?

Comment: I only have hourly data, and i need to find the hours where the peak occurs. So say the server load was very high between, 2-4 pm, and 6-7 pm. I can find that there is atleast one peak, but i also need to be able to tell that peaks are at 2-4 and 6-7